clickhouse memory usage of server without queries
I have a clickhouse server on a 32Gb instance that is using 13Gb of memory when no queries are running.  Is there a way to reduce this usage of "background" memory?

Look to
https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-who-ate-my-memory/

My issue was that I had a "join" table of 12Gb.  After deleting that, the memory usage went to about 1Gb.
Went investigating, I did this query:
SELECT
    metric, description, formatReadableSize(value) size
FROM
    system.asynchronous_metrics
WHERE
    metric like '%Cach%'
    or metric like '%Mem%'
order by
    value desc;

It showed MemoryResident was 13G, so I also tried max_server_memory_usage_to_ram_ratio and max_server_memory_usage but those weren't right.
MemoryResident is 1000Mb now that the join table is gone.

I suspect it might be the cache size 12GB which definitely uses main memory. When the table is deleted, its cache should be deleted as well.

Join table data is always located in the RAM. This is why after deleting the table, memory usage went down.
See https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/join#data-storage
